# C# Cast Object to Generic Interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to create CQRS in my small project and I need to cast object to Interface that has generic parameter.

edit: typo fixed

```cs
NewUsersIdsMessageHandler newUserHandler = new NewUsersIdsMessageHandler();
IMessageHandler<IMessage> handler = newUserHandler; // compilation error


    public class NewUsersIdsMessage : IMessage
    {
        public NewUsersTroopRequestIdsMessage()
        {
        }
    }


    public class NewUsersIdsMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<NewUsersIdsMessage >
    {
        public NewUsersIdsMessageHandler()
        {
        }
    }

    public interface IMessageHandler<in TType>
        where TType : IMessage
    {
        Task<bool> Handle(TType message);
    }
```

How can I assign ?

```cs
IMessageHandler<IMessage> handler = new NewUsersIdsMessageHandler();
```

I know that I can assign

```
IMessageHandler<NewUsersIdsMessage> handler = new NewUsersIdsMessageHandler();
```

but that is not universal enough for me.
Thanks!

Comment: an `IMessageHandler<IMessage>` can have `Handle` called on it with a parameter of **any** type the derives from `IMessage`. `NewUsersIDsMessageHandler` is only prepared to deal with `NewUsersIdsMessage` objects (or those specifically derived from it). Do you see why you're not allowed to assign one to the other?

Comment: They're different in types you can't just make your concrete class generic `new MessageHandler<T>()` and dump the NewUsersIdsMessageHandler

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.

This interface

```
public interface IMessageHandler<out TType> where TType : IMessage
{
    bool Handle(TType Message);
}
```

cannot have `<out TType>` specification, since TType acts as an input parameter.

While having `<out TType>` specification is required to be able to assign like this:

```
IMessageHandler<IMessage> handler = newUserHandler;
```

This is called [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

Logically thinking: `IMessageHandler<IMessage>` can handle any type of message, while `newUserHandle` can handle only specific messages, so this assignment cannot go through static type-check at compile-time, as it might cause runtime error.

In case the ultimate goal is to be able to find the appropriate handler for given message type, you can use IoC containers, e.g. Autofac; Here is how it will help you:

```
builder
.Register(typeof(NewUsersIdsMessageHandler))
.As(typeof(IMessageHandler<NewUsersIdsMessage>))
.InstancePerDependency();
```

Then in code

```
var handler = container.Resolve<IMessageHandler<NewUserIdsMessage>>()
```